# Update a local variable name by a dynamic name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following <strike>global</strike> *local* variables `one` and `two` declared.

I also have an object of all the variables that I have with their starting values.

The problem I am running into is that after checking to see if the variable has a localStorage value or not I want to assign the 'count' to the <strike>global</strike> local variable, but I don't know how to assign it to the global variable when all I have is 'key'.

I could make if statements for every global variable like

```
if( key == "one" )  { one == count }
```

but that would be tedious, is there an easier way to do this?

```
game = new Game();
function Game(){

    var one;
    var two;

    var variableStart = {
       "one":"100",
       "two":"200"
    }

    $.each(variableStart, function(){
        this.checkVariableValue = function( vName ){
            if( typeof localStorage[vName] == 'undefined' && localStorage[vName] == null )     {
               return false;
            }
            else{
                return localStorage[vName];
            }
        }
        var count;

        if( this.checkVariableValue( key ) == false ){
            count = value;
        }
        else{
            count = this.checkVariableValue(key);
        }

        if( key == one ){
            one = count;
        }
        else if( key == two ){
            two = count;
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: BTW, welcome to StackOverflow.  I updated your question based on the details below to make it easier for anyone who finds it to understand what is going on.  Just one more quick note: `variableStart` is an *object*, not an array.  I know that some languages like PHP allow numeric arrays and associative arrays to be used interchangeably, JavaScript does not.  Second: **Thanks for looking at your code and thinking "There has to be a better way to do that."**   That really is a good sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, using global variables like this really is bad coding.

Second, using two separate variables like that is bad coding.

That said,  I'll show you how to do what you are trying to do:

```
// Instead of:
var globalName = key;
globalName = count;

// Take advantage of the fact that globals can be accessed off the 'window' object.
window[key] = count;
```

**How to do it a cleaner way**

It would be better to have a single global object, perhaps called counts:

```
var counts = {};
```

Then, when you go to assign values:

```
counts[key] = counts;
```

Comment: yeah I am new to js, I have everything in an object called Game, would that make a difference?

Comment: I should have read question better, I took your question title at its word.  Since those variable declarations are *inside* a function, then they are not -- by their very definition -- global.  You're better off doing what I said in the "cleaner" way and replace the 'var one;' and 'var two;' with the 'counts' object.

Comment: Awesome that worked, and is a lot cleaner. Sorry for the confusion, that was my fault

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like this. All global variables are available in the global element (normally `window`)

```
window[key] = count
```

Comment: window[key] isn't working, check my edit. I have the global variables declared in an object called Game